# Why does maxlength have no effect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```jsx
<input class="input {{fields[$index].class}}" 
  ng-disabled="field.disabled != ''"  
  ng-required="field.name == zipcode"
  ng-model="fields[$index].value"
  name="{{field.name}}"
  type="{{field.type}}"
  id="{{field.name}}"
  maxlength="6"
>
<label placeholder=" {{field.label}}">

</label>
```

The attribute maxlength="6" has no effect for me.

I wanted to make it so that no more than 6 characters can be entered into the textbox. However, I can just keep typing numbers, and the textbox shows them.

The user should be able to enter a certain zip code, and these zip codes are always 6 characters in my country and only digits.

The textbox accepts only numbers, that works, but it keeps accepting any amount of numbers / characters.

What is going wrong here?

Thank you!

Edit: Somebody posted my code with the ability to run it, and it works as expected.

It would be great if this question would not be closed so that we can still find out the problem with the original version and post the problem / solution then.

Edit: Here is some more of my code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox ">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Mein Profil</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <form>
                        <div ng-repeat="field in fields track by $index" class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                               
                                <!-- alert({{field.name}});
                                alert({{field.type}});
                                alert({{fields[$index].class}}); -->
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="input {{fields[$index].class}}" 
                                    ng-disabled="field.disabled != ''"  
                                    ng-required="field.name == zipcode"
                                    ng-model="fields[$index].value"
                                    name="{{field.name}}"
                                    type="{{field.type}}"
                                    id="{{field.name}}"
                                    ng-maxlength="6"
                                  >
                                  <label placeholder=" {{field.label}}">
                                           
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-5">
                               
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="input {{fields[$index].class}}" 
                                    ng-disabled="field.disabled != ''"  
                                    ng-required="field.name == zipcode"
                                    ng-model="fields[$index].value"
                                    name="{{field.name}}"
                                    type="{{field.type}}"
                                    id="{{field.name}}"
                                    ng-maxlength="6"
                                  >
                                  <label placeholder=" {{field.label}}">
                                           
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->

                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-5">
                               
                               
                                   
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input ng-if="fields2[$index].label != 'PLZ'" ng-disabled="fields2[$index].disabled != ''" class="input {{fields[$index].class}}" required='' id="{{fields2[$index].name}}"
                                      
                                    name="{{fields2[$index].name}}" ng-model="fields2[$index].value" type="{{fields2[$index].type}}"
                                    maxlength="255">
                                    <input ng-if="fields2[$index].label == 'PLZ'" ng-disabled="fields2[$index].disabled != ''" class="input {{fields[$index].class}}" required='' id="{{fields2[$index].name}}"
                                        only-numbers
                                        name="{{fields2[$index].name}}" ng-model="fields2[$index].value" type="{{fields2[$index].type}}"
                                        maxlength="255">
                                        <label placeholder=" {{fields2[$index].label}}">
                                           
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                        <div  class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">

                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input  class="input" autocomplete="new-password"
                                        name="new_password" ng-model="new_password"  type="password" id="new_password"
                                        maxlength="255">
                                        <label placeholder=" Neues Passwort">
                                   
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input  class="input" autocomplete="new-password"
                                        name="confirm_password" ng-model="confirm_password"  type="password" id="confirm_password"
                                        maxlength="255">
                                        <label placeholder=" Neues Passwort bestätigen"></label>
                                   
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <!-- <button ng-click="handleActionUpdateProfile()" name="submit" id="create-tan"
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">

                                Profil aktualisieren
                            </button> -->
                            <md-button id="create-tan"  ng-click="handleActionUpdateProfile()" type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary register-btn m-0 px-4">
                                Profil aktualisieren
                            </md-button>
                        </div>
                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Must be something else, because this code is fine as-is HTML.

Comment: You used other ng directives, why not `ng-maxlength`?

Comment: Can you give more information on  `The attribute maxlength="6" has no effect for me.` ? `maxlength` has effects on some kind of input only (text, password,  email....but not number).

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh Thank you. I have added some info in the post.

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you, but ng-maxlength doesn't have any either effect either.

Comment: @tmighty  what is exactly the type of the input `type="{{field.type}}"`? Like I said, max-length has no effects on number. I think the type should be text, and you can use ng-pattern to control the format (for example : `[\d]{6}`)

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh I am not sure if you are right. In the answer that SebastianRiechner posted, it works. field.type is "number".

Comment: I see your point, I tested [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_maxlength). For the snippet, I can put letter in the input (or I don't know how to run it correctly). I think when the type is number, you cannot put letter in , and there is an arrow in the right side to increase/decrease the value.

Comment: Create a demo in a sandbox site the demonstrates the issue. Looks like that is in an `ng-repeat` and we don't know what the various `fields` values are for `type`, `disabled` etc are

Comment: As mentioned above maxlength doesn't work for number type and you will need to write a custom validator probably if that is the type used. Should be able to easily search for examples

Comment: If I can have a theory argument, when we use type = "text", the value is a string, and strings have the property "length". When we have type = "number", the value is a number and number don't have property length :)

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh actually the `value` is string for both. To get actual number you need `valueAsNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else interferring. If you look at the isolated snippet that you posted, it is not possible to enter more than those 6 characters. Check out the following snippet.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<input class="input {{fields[$index].class}}" 
  ng-disabled="field.disabled != ''"  
  ng-required="field.name == zipcode"
  ng-model="fields[$index].value"
  name="{{field.name}}"
  type="{{field.type}}"
  id="{{field.name}}"
  maxlength="6"
>
<label placeholder=" {{field.label}}">

</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. Your sample works as expected. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, I will. I would still like to find out what the reason for my error is, ok?

Comment: What else could I check it for a probable cause?

Comment: Without seeing any other code it is hard to tell...

Comment: I have added some more at the end of my posting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`maxlength` only works on `type="text"` input. It does not work on `number` inputs for example.